# How to configure logging of insert statements using pgAdmin?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I want to use `pgAdmin` to configure to log all `sql insert` statements. But how?

I found the `Backend Configuration Editor` and enabled `log_statement=all`. But how can I control the file to that the log statements are written? (eg: c\logs.txt)

Comment: See [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html). You probably want to set `log_directory`.

Answer (score 0):

```
log_destination = 'stderr,csvlog'
log_statement = 'all'

@see C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\data\pg_log
```

Answer (score 0):

See [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html). You probably want to set `log_directory` and `log_filename`.

You *cannot* set individual log destinations for particular categories of log line - say, log statements to one file, other logs to another file. This would be a nice feature; if you have time, consider raising the idea on pgsql-hackers and after discussion submitting a suitable patch.

Most people use `csvlog`, or use text logs with a `log_line_prefix` set, then filter the logs with simple tools like `grep` to extract the desired information.

For statement data collection, also have a look at the `pg_stat_statements` extension.